# wordpress custom taxonomy parent link show static content how?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am new to wordpress. I have created custom post type attach to a custom taxonomy its working fine and also created custom taxonomy template like
taxonomy-medispa.php(Taxonomy - medispa).

In this template left hand side list the child terms of taxonomy(medispa) associate with links. on the right hand side some static contents regd (taxonomy: medispa).

**Now the condition is once i click the taxonomy term link from left side list the corresponding post to the term link, otherwise it show the static content.**

Currently when click the parent link (medispa) and their term link both list the  corresponding post.

I need when click the term link it show the posts, but click the parent taxonomy(medispa) show static content.

```
<?php 
        //start by fetching the terms for the medispa taxonomy
        $terms = get_terms( 'medispa', array(   
        'orderby'    => 'id',
        'hide_empty' => 0
        ));

        echo '<ul>';

        foreach($terms as $term)
        {
            if($term->parent !=0)
            {
               echo '<a href="'.get_term_link((int)$term->term_id, $term->taxonomy).'"><li>'.$term->name.'</li>
               </a>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';   
?>



    <?php /* The loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


    <?php //get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```